# Munin combine network traffic graph from multiple servers

Tags: munin

I've been searching through munin wiki and docs, tried various combinations for setting custom graphs but all ended unsuccessfull.

Thing is that I actually cannot understand the mechanism behind creating custom graphs at all, and all I was doing was trial and error effort without understanding what actually happend. Munin docs are very poor on this matter.

I am trying to simply generate a graph with network traffic from 5 servers, so I can have quick comparisment of the traffic on each.

I am monitoring just if_eth0 on 5 servers and want to have one more graph with all 5 servers shown there.

Comment: Have you read http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/LoaningData and http://guide.munin-monitoring.org/en/latest/tutorial/troubleshooting.html?highlight=loan#check-data-collection ? What I would do:
1. make sure the graph with network traffic from one server is working
2. do this for all 5 servers
3. combine (loan) the data (see first link)

Answer (score 0):

In default /etc/munin/munin.conf (stable 2.0) you find this template:

```
# A more complex example of a host tree
#
## First our "normal" host.
# [fii.foo.com]
#       address foo
#
## Then our other host...
# [fay.foo.com]
#       address fay
#
## IPv6 host. note that the ip adress has to be in brackets
# [ip6.foo.com]
#       address [2001::1234:1]
#
## Then we want totals...
# [foo.com;Totals] #Force it into the "foo.com"-domain...
#       update no   # Turn off data-fetching for this "host".
#
#   # The graph "load1". We want to see the loads of both machines...
#   # "fii=fii.foo.com:load.load" means "label=machine:graph.field"
#       load1.graph_title Loads side by side
#       load1.graph_order fii=fii.foo.com:load.load fay=fay.foo.com:load.load
#
#   # The graph "load2". Now we want them stacked on top of each other.
#       load2.graph_title Loads on top of each other
#       load2.dummy_field.stack fii=fii.foo.com:load.load fay=fay.foo.com:load.load
#       load2.dummy_field.draw AREA # We want area instead the default LINE2.
#       load2.dummy_field.label dummy # This is needed. Silly, really.
#
#   # The graph "load3". Now we want them summarised into one field
#       load3.graph_title Loads summarised
#       load3.combined_loads.sum fii.foo.com:load.load fay.foo.com:load.load
#       load3.combined_loads.label Combined loads # Must be set, as this is
#                                                 # not a dummy field!
#
## ...and on a side note, I want them listen in another order (default is
## alphabetically)
#
# # Since [foo.com] would be interpreted as a host in the domain "com", we
# # specify that this is a domain by adding a semicolon.
# [foo.com;]
#       node_order Totals fii.foo.com fay.foo.com
```

And this example creates a new graph showing the load of two servers (taken from http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/LoaningData ):

```
[example.org;Overview]
address 127.0.0.1 
use_node_name no
update no

loadall.update no
loadall.graph_title Load of all servers
loadall.graph_args --base 1000  
loadall.graph_vlabel Load
loadall.graph_scale no
loadall.graph_category system

loadall.graph_order \
    Server1=sv1.example.org:load.load \
    Server2=sv2.example.org:load.load
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that is not right away apparent is that every host must belong to some group. So, this [syntax](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.1.9-1/master/lib/Munin/Master/Config.pm#L440) is [invalid](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.1.9-1/master/lib/Munin/Master/Config.pm#L378-L429):

```
[;myhost]
    address  ip.add.re.ss;
```

And this way you get a group with no hosts:

```
[myhost;]
    ...
```

You can check it by adding the following code after [the following line](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.1.9-1/master/lib/Munin/Master/Update.pm#L27):

```
foreach my $k (keys %$gah) {
    DEBUG "-- $k";
    foreach my $h (keys %{$gah->{$k}{'hosts'}}) {
        DEBUG "   $h";
    }
}
```

Then run (a lot of output, you might probably want to add `| tail -n 100` or something):

```
$ su - munin -s /bin/bash -c '/usr/share/munin/munin-update --debug'
...
2019/06/14 16:31:43 -- myhost1
2019/06/14 16:31:43 -- myhost2
2019/06/14 16:31:43    myhost2
2019/06/14 16:31:43 -- myhost3
2019/06/14 16:31:43    myhost3
...
```

So,

```
[myhost]                 # group "myhost", conaining host "myhost"
[foo.com]                # group "com", containing host "foo.com"
[group;foo.com]          # group "group", containing host "foo.com"
[group1;group2;foo.com]  # group "group1", containing group "group2",
                         # which in its turn contains host "foo.com"
```

**With that out of the way,** the syntax is basically as follows:

```
[group1;host1]
    ...
[group1;host2]
    ...
[group1;virt_host1]
    virt_plugin1.graph_title Some title
    virt_plugin1.graph_order resulting_field_name1=host1:plugin1.field_name1 resulting_field_name2=host2:plugin2.field_name2
```

`virt_plugin1`, `resulting_field_name1`, `resulting_field_name2` are all arbitrary names. `virt_plugin1` appears in the breadcrumbs of the page. `resulting_field_name*` becomes a graph's label. Unless you override it:

```
[group1;virt_host1]
    ...
    virt_plugin1.resulting_field_name1.label = my_field_name
```

Regarding where to get (how to confirm) plugin and field names (data sources):

```
$ nc host1 4949
# munin node at host1
fetch plugin1
field_name1.value 0.17
.
```

Then, if you're borrowing data from a different group, you've got to specify it explicitly:

```
[group1;host1]
    ...
[group2;host2]
    ...
[group2;virt_host1]
    virt_plugin1.graph_title Some title
    virt_plugin1.graph_order resulting_field_name1=group1:host1.plugin1.field_name1 resulting_field_name2=host2:plugin2.field_name2
```

A note on when to expect changes to the config to **take effect.**

When `html_strategy` is `cgi`, [`munin-html`](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/debian/munin.cron.d#L7) (as part of `munin-cron`) [writes](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/_bin/munin-cron.in#L16) [state](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/_bin/munin-html.in#L40) to [`/var/lib/munin/htmlconf.storable`](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/lib/Munin/Master/HTMLOld.pm#L194) every [5 minutes](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/lib/Munin/Master/HTMLOld.pm#L184). The state contains settings of every host, and is [used](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/_bin/munin-cgi-html.in#L55) by [`munin-cgi-html`](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/lib/Munin/Master/HTMLOld.pm#L160) as a [config](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/lib/Munin/Master/HTMLConfig.pm#L39).

So, either you wait for the next update, or trigger the update yourself:

```
$ su - munin -s /bin/bash -c /usr/share/munin/munin-html
```

Or:

```
$ su - munin -s /bin/bash -c munin-cron
```

In the [same](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/_bin/munin-cron.in#L6) [vein](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/_bin/munin-update.in#L39), [`munin-update`](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/lib/Munin/Master/Update.pm#L56) [updates](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/lib/Munin/Master/Update.pm#L278) [`/var/lib/munin/datafile.storable`](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/lib/Munin/Master/Update.pm#L316). But `datafile` part is marked to [include base](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/lib/Munin/Master/Utils.pm#L101), as opposed to [`htmlconf`](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/lib/Munin/Master/Utils.pm#L113) one. Which means that contents of `/etc/munin/munin.conf` is [merged](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/lib/Munin/Master/Utils.pm#L965) into `datafile` part. And `munin-cgi-graph` uses `datafile` part for a [config](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/lib/Munin/Master/GraphOld.pm#L369).

So you can just restart `munin-cgi-graph` for it to notice the changes.

And the [last](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/_bin/munin-cgi-graph.in#L49-L55) [thing](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/_bin/munin-cgi-graph.in#L134-L135), [`munin-cgi-graph`](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/_bin/munin-cgi-graph.in#L180) [sets](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/_bin/munin-cgi-graph.in#L193) [`Expires`](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/debian/2.0.49-1/master/_bin/munin-cgi-graph.in#L291) header. That means you've got to somehow reset/disable browser cache for browser to make the request.

In case you notify one of them, but not the other... Let me leave it as an exercise for the reader :)